# slim PHP Get parameters

Tags: web-services, rest, slim, router, getparameter

get attributes from the URI using Slim 2 Framwork

http://localhost:8080/serverEndModule1/v1/varifyi**d=OQ==&code=1e212ffc375e52a9c6e7debe8adcc17** 
using the following Code:

```
$app->get('/varify', function () use ($app) {
$id = $app->request->get('id');
$paramValue2 = $app->request->get('code');
$db = new DbOperation();
$response = array();
$db->userVarify($id, $code); // send to database
```

help me to implement the following $app->get route .

Comment: Please provide a specific question along with information on what you have implemented and how it does not work compared to your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I got it now it' working

$app->get('/varify',  function() use ($app){

```
 $req = $app->request();
$id = $req->get('id');   // 
$code = $req->get('code');


 $db = new DbOperation();
$response = array();
```

$res= $db->userVarify($id, $code);
}